# HTML input field need to take characters from beginning when full

Tags: javascript, html, keyevent

I need a text box which when maxlength is reached, need to position cursor to beginning and on key input needs to replace the characters as keys are pressed. My sample code is below. I can get cursor to start of textbox when maxlength is reached, but the characters are not replaced. Please share any ideas on how I can change the default input field behavior.

https://jsfiddle.net/yd62jugk/7/

```js
function myFunction() {  
  if (document.getElementById("demo").selectionStart === 
      parseInt(document.getElementById("demo").getAttribute('maxlength'), 10)) {
      document.getElementById("demo").setSelectionRange(0,0);  
  }
}
```

```html
<p>Press keys.</p>
<input type="text" id="demo" maxlength=5 onkeyup="myFunction()">
```

Comment: Guys maybe it’s a game or something, maybe a naive exercise, maybe he was handed the requirement and has no office. It’s helpful to point out that in a general app it’s a bad idea, but ufufufufuf...give the guy a break.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const input = document.querySelector('input');
const maxLength = Number(input.getAttribute('maxlength'));

input.addEventListener('keydown',(e)=>{
  let value=input.value;
  let start=input.selectionStart;
  value[start+1]=e.keyCode; 

  input.setSelectionRange(start,start+1);
  input.value=value;
  if (start===maxLength){
    input.setSelectionRange(0,1);
  }
});
console.log(maxLength);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<p>Press a key inside the text field to set a red background color.</p>

<input type="text" id="demo" maxlength="5">

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: its probably because I was in a rush and didn't see why I was not getting back to proper value but with some spaces...noticing now that the quotes for max-length are not proper in his html

Answer (score 0):

```js
const demo = document.getElementById("demo")

demo.addEventListener("keyup", myFunction )
let cursor_position = 1
let can_update = false

function myFunction(e) { 
  let max = parseInt(demo.getAttribute('maxlength'), 10)
  if ( can_update ) {
    e.target.value = replaceAt(e.target.value, cursor_position - 1, e.key)
    demo.setSelectionRange(cursor_position, cursor_position);
    (cursor_position < max ) ? cursor_position++ : cursor_position = 1
  } else if (demo.value.length === max) { can_update = true }
}

const replaceAt = (str, index, replacement) => str.substr(0, index) + replacement + str.substr(index + replacement.length)
```